# Is Advantage Database Server v11.1.30 .Net Data Provider compatible with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, advantage-database-server

Is Advantage Database Server v11.1.30  .Net Data Provider compatible with Visual Studio 2019?
Evaluating .Net Core compatibility with Advantage Database Server.

Answer (score 1):

It may work with VS 2019 but I do not think it is .Net Core compatible. The 11.x .Net Data Provider was released long before the .NET Core was released. I doubt that it does not rely on any non-Core component.